# How to dynamically position title above each table in a single PDF file using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to populate multiple table in a single PDF file using JSPDF client library. I am able to populate the table one by one but I am not able to set the tile above each table dynamically because each table has different number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this to get where the last row was drawn on the page `doc.autoTable.previous.finalY`